# Is VARARRAY a data type in DB2?

Tags: java, spring, db2

VARARRAY a data type in DB2? If so how can i invoke a stored procedure with IN parameter as VARARRAY using simpleJdbcCall using Java.

Comment: Your question might not be answerable because it is very broad and lacks context, for example a [mcve] Also, what have you tried to solve this? See also: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

`VARARRAY` is not a data type in Db2.

For the list of Db2 data types you can look here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008483.html

Db2 does support array types in Procedures however, see this page for details

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0052894.html

Comment: Thanks. This was actually a dumb question. VARARRAY which I was searching was actually a user-defined type.